# creating another Oncreate in same activity

Tags: java, android

I'm trying to add a second onCreate but when I did it it is not working , the first one which is `Oncreate` works well when I press the `TextView` it does the job and takes me to SecondActivity but when I press on the second one which calls `Oncreate1` it doesn't do the job for me and takes me to FirstActivity even though i did the exact same thing I did for the `Oncreate` I don't know what's the problem I hope you can help me

This is the logcat

```
    12-26 04:13:27.390: I/Ads(1808): Ad url modified to http://googleads.g.doubleclick.net:80/mads/gma?preqs=0&session_id=7802952340037714008&seq_num=1&u_w=384&msid=imamalsajadsayings.android.com&cap=m%2Ca&js=afma-sdk-a-v6.4.1&bas_off=0&net=ed&app_name=3.android.imamalsajadsayings.android.com&hl=en&gnt=3&carrier=310260&u_audio=4&kw&u_sd=2&ms=MMbiAdsTBWDvSdyekwxcU1HfnPY0zVDgymfntXc0HtctkjVkiQVLwpyucG2sYhOjA-oCD3ttwEUCEaLiC7z810qPte8UcMBibTH6mFdmFZpFqMtfE-ZQ-qbdeoxgUiVSgJYqK4bpoDU_WFa3wexgrJAYtMktIhKFa_6IELwlqNqTS157Vrm5Cv-95PJq-kHr-EorriTQzyw0HE_eBM5KrLg2JcAZwS1uXPDGOehjdapmAyJ7FZJ_YTg1Vr85Ux94RIqrdwPvOiLW1BzOFEtNtmMmsb47xAjv-fEYOrG_0DnHIwK-CXcnifK8wHi2RTSkWyNxiIqxPc6RNxvG7GD8Ww&format=320x50_mb&oar=0&u_h=592&bas_on=0&ptime=0&imbf=8008&u_so=p&output=html&region=mobile_app&u_tz=-300&client_sdk=1&ex=1&slotname=a152b5665edfefd&kw_type=broad&gsb=3g&caps=inlineVideo_interactiveVideo_mraid1_th_autoplay_mediation_sdkAdmobApiForAds_di&jsv=66&urll=909
    12-26 04:13:27.390: I/Ads(1808): Request scenario: Online server request.
    12-26 04:13:31.650: W/EGL_emulation(1808): eglSurfaceAttrib not implemented
    12-26 04:13:31.890: I/Choreographer(1808): Skipped 34 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
    12-26 04:13:35.060: I/Choreographer(1808): Skipped 75 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
    12-26 04:13:37.470: W/EGL_emulation(1808): eglSurfaceAttrib not implemented
     12-26 04:13:38.380: I/Ads(1808): onReceiveAd()
      12-26 04:13:39.140: E/eglCodecCommon(1808): glUtilsParamSize: unknow param   0x00000b44
       12-26 04:13:39.180: E/eglCodecCommon(1808): glUtilsParamSize: unknow param 0x00000bd0
     12-26 04:13:39.400: I/chromium(1808): [INFO:async_pixel_transfer_manager_android.cc(56)] Async pixel transfers not supported
     12-26 04:13:40.010: I/chromium(1808): [INFO:async_pixel_transfer_manager_android.cc(56)] Async pixel transfers not supported
     12-26 04:13:40.170: E/eglCodecCommon(1808): **** ERROR unknown type 0x0 (glSizeof,72)
     12-26 04:13:40.550: I/Choreographer(1808): Skipped 86 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
        12-26 04:13:40.590: E/eglCodecCommon(1808): glUtilsParamSize: unknow param 0x00000b44
       12-26 04:13:40.610: E/eglCodecCommon(1808): glUtilsParamSize: unknow param 0x00000bd0
       12-26 04:13:40.870: E/eglCodecCommon(1808): **** ERROR unknown type 0x0 (glSizeof,72)
       12-26 04:13:41.300: E/eglCodecCommon(1808): glUtilsParamSize: unknow param 0x00000b44
       12-26 04:13:41.310: E/eglCodecCommon(1808): glUtilsParamSize: unknow param 0x00000bd0
        12-26 04:13:41.390: E/eglCodecCommon(1808): **** ERROR unknown type 0x0 (glSizeof,72)
        12-26 04:13:41.520: E/eglCodecCommon(1808): glUtilsParamSize: unknow param 0x00000b44
        12-26 04:13:41.560: E/eglCodecCommon(1808): glUtilsParamSize: unknow param 0x00000bd0
        12-26 04:13:41.740: E/eglCodecCommon(1808): **** ERROR unknown type 0x0 (glSizeof,72)
        12-26 04:13:41.830: E/eglCodecCommon(1808): glUtilsParamSize: unknow param 0x00000b44
        12-26 04:13:41.850: E/eglCodecCommon(1808): glUtilsParamSize: unknow param 0x00000bd0
         12-26 04:13:41.910: E/eglCodecCommon(1808): **** ERROR unknown type 0x0 (glSizeof,72)
        12-26 04:13:42.070: E/eglCodecCommon(1808): glUtilsParamSize: unknow param 0x00000b44
        12-26 04:13:42.090: E/eglCodecCommon(1808): glUtilsParamSize: unknow param 0x00000bd0
```

.
and this is the `MainActivity`

```
package imamalsajadsayings.android.com;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    private TextView mTextView;
    private TextView mTextView1;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        mTextView = (TextView) findViewById( R.id.state2 );
        mTextView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity.this,SecondActivity.class);
                startActivity(i);

            }
        });
    }

    protected void onCreate1(Bundle savedInstanceState)
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        mTextView1 = (TextView) findViewById( R.id.state1 );
        mTextView1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity.this,FirstActivity.class);
                startActivity(i);
            }
        });
    }


    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items TO the action bar IF it IS present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

}
```

I wish you can help me to make `Oncreate1` works too....

Thanks in advance

Comment: why do you want to use like this?

Comment: Do you even know what you're doing? Go through the android tutorials first.

Comment: i have the functions but i don't know why it is not working

the Oncreate1 isn't working

Comment: You should first read android life cycle.go to this link http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#ActivityLifecycle

Comment: onCreate()1 is your own method, not provided by android framework so you need to call this method explicitly and for your kind information, you can't call Activity onCreate() method by your own. This method is called when the activity first created and after that only onStart() called every time u switch the control to that activity.

Answer (score 2):

The method is named `onCreate()`, and it will be run (as the name implies) on creation. If you create a method called `onCreate1()` it will be exactly the same as if you created a method called `neverCallThisMethodAutomatically()`, i.e. you need to call it manually if you want it to be run.

Just because the method name resembles `onCreate()` doesn't mean that it will behave anything like it.

Comment: and what can i do to create another onCreate?

Comment: There's only a single onCreate per Activity. All the code that you want to be run on creation needs to be in that single method.

Comment: but then how will i be able to make the onClick refer to the state1 or state2?

Answer (score 2):

Now Oncreate1() is your own method it is not override by Activity you have to call  Oncreate1()

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure where to begin...

I'll start by saying that calling `super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);` in `OnCreate1()` is probably not a good idea.
Having said that... This whole implementation is VERY wrong. Please consider changing to [fragments](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html), it will suite you better if I understand you correctly.

Please also read about [Application Fundamentals](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/fundamentals.html), [Intents](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/intents-filters.html), [Activities](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/activities.html) and [Java Inheritance](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/subclasses.html)

Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

Use like and refer [Android life cycle](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#ActivityLifecycle),

```
package imamalsajadsayings.android.com;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    private TextView mTextView;
    private TextView mTextView1;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        mTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.state2);
        mTextView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity.this, SecondActivity.class);
                startActivity(i);

            }
        });
        mTextView1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.state1);
        mTextView1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity.this, FirstActivity.class);
                startActivity(i);
            }
        });

    }



    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items TO the action bar IF it IS present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;



    }
```

Comment: thanks much, but it's now crashing the app when i click on the textview

Comment: Did you mention your Activity in your manifest file

Comment: ooooh i totally forgot yees thanks much dude!

Comment: hmm fine.. And you need to learn lot in development and all the best :)

Comment: working! thanks much, atleast someone helped instead of acting smart like others :D

Comment: hmm thanks, you can also be an expert after a few months and you need to put lot of effort for it :)